# How to filter an object based on a datetime range in python (Django)

Tags: python, django, datetime, filtering

I am trying to create a page with all the most recent posts.

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     postTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I found this example:

```
 start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
 end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
 Post.objects.filter(postTime__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

I know I'm suppose to use the __range function. But how can I make it so that I can get all the posts from a range of **today all the way to two weeks ago**

**something like this:**

```
start_date = datetime.date(date from two weeks ago)
end_date = datetime.date(currentdate)
Post.objects.filter(postTime__range(start_date, end_date))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start_date = end_date - datetime.timedelta(days=14)
```

Comment: this is what I have in my tastypie resource:

Comment: queryset=Post.objects.filter(postTime__range=(date.today(), date.today() - timedelta(days=14)))

Comment: @RiegieGodwin, I think you have your start and end times reversed.

Comment: I reposted my question here because I believe I did not explain my question properly, please do take a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487537/how-to-filter-an-object-based-on-a-datetimefield-range-in-python-django-using

Comment: I tried what you suggested as follows queryset=Post.objects.filter(date.today-timedelta(days=14), date.today())) but I was still unable retrieve the objects

Comment: I decided to do the filtering through get_object_list and reversed it just like you said, it worked like a charm, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

Post.objects.filter(postTime__range=(date.today(), date.today() - timedelta(days=14)))
```

Comment: I tried your method and I'm still unable to retrieve those objects.

Comment: queryset=Post.objects.filter(postTime__range=(date.today(), date.today() - timedelta(days=14)))

Comment: I reposted my question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487537/how-to-filter-an-object-based-on-a-datetimefield-range-in-python-django-using