# How to filter an object based on a DateTimeField range in Python (Django) using Tastypie

Tags: python, django, datetime, filtering, tastypie

How can one filter an object based on a **datetime field** range using **Tastypie**.

I have a **Post model**:

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
     postTime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=140)
```

The post objects are retrieved through **Tastypie**. The range of objects I would like to retrieve are all the objects created from today to all the objects created 3 days ago. So I tried filtering the objects from the queryset as follows

```
RecentPosts(ModelResource):
     class Meta:
          queryset= Post.objects.filter(postTime__range=(date.today(), date.today() -timedelta(days=3)))
          resource_name = 'recent-posts'
          fields = ['id','postTime']
          authentication = BasicAuthentication()
          authorization =DjangoAuthorization()
          serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
          include_resource_uri = False
          filtering = {
                            'postTime': ALL,
                            'description': ALL,
          }
```

Even after doing this I'm unable to retrieve the objects. How else can I go about this?

Comment: Please go back to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15482775/how-to-filter-an-object-based-on-a-datetime-range-in-python-django/15482817?noredirect=1#comment21924252_15482817). I still think you have the start and end times of your range in the wrong order.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436229/tastypie-filtering-with-multiple-values/11438100#11438100

Comment: @MarkRansom I managed to find a working solution using Tastypie, I have posted the answer below, please do check it out!

Comment: @Catherine I managed to find a working solution using Tastypie, I have posted the answer below, please do check it out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending hours fiddling with different solutions, I finally found one that works. What I did was, instead of doing the filtering from the queryset I did the filtering in **object_get_list** Here is my solution. Also make sure you have the proper imports as well

```
 from datetime import datetime, timedelta

 RecentPosts(ModelResource):
 class Meta:
      queryset= Post.objects.all()
      resource_name = 'recent-posts'
      fields = ['id','postTime']
      authentication = BasicAuthentication()
      authorization =DjangoAuthorization()
      serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
      include_resource_uri = False
      filtering = {
                        'postTime': ALL,
                        'description': ALL,
      }
 get_object_list(self, request):
      return super(RecentPosts, self).get_object_list.filter(postTime__range=(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=3), datetime.now()))
```

This will return all objects created from the current date to all the objects from 3 days ago. Try this solution out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: That's cool idea. I am only wondering if this is "idiomatic Django" (not that I care so much about such things ;)). People use also for that apply_filters (see for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436229/tastypie-filtering-with-multiple-values/11438100#11438100)

Comment: This approach is also officially documented. See here: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.10.0/cookbook.html#per-request-alterations-to-the-queryset and here: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/v0.10.0/resources.html#queryset

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to use

```
filtering = {
   "postTime": ['gte', 'lte'],
}
```

and then in the query which is calling the resource add

```
http://your.query/?postTime__lte=<SOME DATE>&postTime__gte=<SOME DATE>
```

You can also choose

```
filtering = {
   "postTime": ['gte',],
}
```

or

```
filtering = {
   "postTime": ['lte',],
}
```

with a proper query.

Comment: @PiotKochaniski, this wasn't exactly what I was looking for however I did find a much easier solution. I'm going to post the answer below, hopefully you can check it out! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a case where I needed this to be handled in query itself. Basically I wanted to use range in the query. I couldn't find any answer. I have done it in the following way. Might help someone:

```
filtering = {
  "postTime": ['range']
}
```

Query using:

```
http://your.query/?postTime__range=<SOME DATE>,<SOME DATE>
```

Returns all the records between these two days!